# Excel Graph for Displaying Running Time Of Different Tasks

Tags: excel, time, graph, charts

I have a list of elapsed times when tasks were running, and I want to create a timing chart for when processes were running. Example data and image below.

| Task | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11:00:01.150 | 11:10:15.015 |
| A | 11:20:17.800 | 11:30:18.505 |
| A | 11:40:19.543 | 11:50:10.250 |
| B | 11:10:32.001 | 11:20:18.220 |
| B | 11:30:15.540 | 11:40:16:015 |
| C | 11:20:19.505 | 11:35:01.003 |
| C | 11:40:17.003 | 12:20:35.019 |

[image: Example Graph]

I have looked into using stacked graphs, but haven't come across a way to show this using those. Is there another type of graph, or another way in which I could display this data as shown in the example using an excel graph?

Answer (score 1):

Like this perhaps, for A and B.  Input data converted to seconds after 11:00

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel is quick and fun for prototyping.

To get exactly the plot you want you have to sit down and actually write some code.

[image]

The application code for this plot is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/timechart